# pandas groupby and remove duplicate

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like

```
       device_id         A        B      C
   4352d38a5c0937da     1.0     2.0  
   4352d38a5c0937da     1.0     2.0  
   4352d38a5c0937da     1.0             3.0  
   4352d38a5c0937da     1.0             3.0
```

Because the value in a column is exactly the same, so I want to groupby device_id to get the result like:

```
       device_id         A        B      C
   4352d38a5c0937da     1.0     2.0     3.0
```

Can somebody help me with that. Thanks.

Comment: `df.groupby('device_id').first()` ?

Comment: thank @anky_91, it works

Answer (score 2):

this groupby should do what you wanted

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([['4352d38a5c0937da', '1.0', '2.0', 'na'], ['4352d38a5c0937da', '1.0', '2.0', 'na'], ['4352d38a5c0937da', '1.0', 'na', '3.0'], ['4352d38a5c0937da', '1.0', 'na', '3.0']], columns=('device_id', 'A', 'B', 'C'))
df.groupby("device_id").max()
```

Comment: `df.groupby(X).first()` would be more memory efficient.